# Why does datatables.net work in my rails development env but not when deployed to heroku?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, datatables

For my first Rails 6 project I'm trying to use [datatables](https://datatables.net/) (jQuery plugin) in combination with bootstrap 5 so that I can get fancy table sorting on every HTML table.

Locally in my rails development environment it works perfectly, but after I push it to my Heroku app, the datatables component does not seem to work: I see all the rows from my database but the column headers are not clickable for sorting and the search bar is gone. For some reason it's not correctly loading / activating the datatables component.

I've scoured SO and the Internet for clues but I can't seem to get to a solution.

Things I've tried with no result:

- toggle `config.assets.compile` option in `production.rb` to force Heroku to precompile assets
- rearranged list of requires in `application.js`
- using `application.js` content of similar SO questions/answers
- looking for clues in developer console (F12) output (I see `Uncaught TypeError` errors but they seem unrelated because I get these also in development and there the datatable works correctly...)

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you run `rake assets:precompile` locally and see what comes out?

Comment: @3DPrintScanner => the precompile output is added to the post.

Comment: Have you popped a `console.log(xx)` into your `cars.js` file to check it's being loaded? have you tried the same code from the developer console?

Comment: Good idea. Did that and it uncovered a whole bunch of errors regarding jQuery. I think i'm mixing different installations of jQuery and datatables. I'll start over from scratch and work my way up to datatables.net.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it eventually by backtracking my steps; generated a new rails 6 app from scratch and carefully testing bootstrap and Datatables.net every step of the way locally and in Heroku.

In case anyone has a similar issue, here is what I did:

1. Generate a new rails 6 app by following Chris Oliver's excellent [Go Rails tutorial](https://gorails.com/episodes/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-webpack-and-rails) on how to install bootstrap on Rails and Webpacker
2. Then install datatables.net by running `yarn add datatables.net-bs4`
3. Add the line `require("datatables.net-bs4")` to `app/javascript/packs/application.js` that it looks something like:

   `require("@rails/ujs").start()`
   `require("turbolinks").start()`
   `require("@rails/activestorage").start()`
   `require("channels")`
   `require("datatables.net-bs4")`
4. And at the end of the file add this (example) code to initialize datatables on your table ID (in my case `#mytable`):

   ```
   $(document).ready( function () {
     $('#mytable').DataTable({
       "lengthMenu": [ [-1, 10, 50, 100], ["All", 10, 50, 100] ]
   });
   ```

   });
5. In your view file (e.g. `index.html.erb`) add an ID attribute to your table (see Datatables.net [manual](https://datatables.net/manual/installation) for more information):

   table class="table" id="**mytable**"

Now the table is correctly working in Heroku. Also there are no console errors about jQuery anymore.

Answer (score -2):

Heroku runs on the Postgresql database. It will not work correctly with other databases. Could you please change your database to postgresql and try throwing the heroku again?

Comment: Both my local and Heroku environment run on Postgresql database so I don't think this is causing Datatables.net to malfunction. I'm seeing the data in the table but the (data)table functionality does not work.